# Upgrading Angular from 15 to 16, ESBuild gets blocked and the update fails. How to upgrade without running esbuild?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to update Angular 15 to 16.  When I run ng update @angular/core@16 @angular/cli@16, it tries to update but at some point "ESBuild.exe" is run and my "ThreatLocker" program blocks it.  Then I end up with no angular build package installed.  I can unblock this, but we have a 3rd party IT company that charges around $100 an hour, so I'm wondering if there's a way to update without running ESBuild.  I don't think it's necessary? Not sure I understand why it's running.  I am using a Visual Studio angular project, but I don't use the run button because the same thing happens. (it tries to run ESBuild.exe and that gets blocked...)  I just use command line commands for ng serve and ng build.

My "npm outdated" output:

```
PM> npm outdated
Package                             Current    Wanted    Latest  Location                                        Depended by
@angular-devkit/build-angular        15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.3  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular      clientapp
@angular/animations                  15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.4  node_modules/@angular/animations                clientapp
@angular/cli                         15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.3  node_modules/@angular/cli                       clientapp
@angular/common                      15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.4  node_modules/@angular/common                    clientapp
@angular/compiler                    15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.4  node_modules/@angular/compiler                  clientapp
@angular/compiler-cli                15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.4  node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli              clientapp
@angular/core                        15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.4  node_modules/@angular/core                      clientapp
@angular/forms                       15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.4  node_modules/@angular/forms                     clientapp
@angular/platform-browser            15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.4  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser          clientapp
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic    15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.4  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic  clientapp
@angular/platform-server             15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.4  node_modules/@angular/platform-server           clientapp
@angular/router                      15.2.9   15.2.10    17.2.4  node_modules/@angular/router                    clientapp
@types/jasmine                        4.0.3     4.0.3     5.1.4  node_modules/@types/jasmine                     clientapp
@types/jasminewd2                    2.0.10    2.0.13    2.0.13  node_modules/@types/jasminewd2                  clientapp
@types/node                        18.17.15  18.19.22  20.11.25  node_modules/@types/node                        clientapp
bootstrap                             5.3.1     5.3.3     5.3.3  node_modules/bootstrap                          clientapp
eslint                               8.49.0    8.57.0    8.57.0  node_modules/eslint                             clientapp
jasmine-core                          4.2.0     4.2.0     5.1.2  node_modules/jasmine-core                       clientapp
karma                                 6.4.2     6.4.3     6.4.3  node_modules/karma                              clientapp
karma-chrome-launcher                 3.1.1     3.1.1     3.2.0  node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher              clientapp
ng-multiselect-dropdown               0.3.9     0.3.9     1.0.0  node_modules/ng-multiselect-dropdown            clientapp
rxjs                                  7.5.7     7.5.7     7.8.1  node_modules/rxjs                               clientapp
typescript                            4.8.2     4.9.5     5.4.2  node_modules/typescript                         clientapp
zone.js                              0.11.8    0.11.8    0.14.4  node_modules/zone.js                            clientapp
```

Comment: Contact whoever runs ThreatLocker to not block esbuild: it's a _pretty_ common build chain tool in JS/TS land (it has _several million more_ weekly downloads than React). This shouldn't be a feature you need to request and pay for, esbuild simply shouldn't get blocked to begin with if this is a hosting service. It's just as much part of modern CI/CD as webpack or even npm.

Comment: It's just a very restrictive environment I'm in here.  It's not that it's flagged as a virus, it's just something where the software needs to be "trained" to allow this to run.  (Same goes for my own executable builds... but once it learns it, it's ok from then on...) From what I've been able to find, though, I shouldn't need to run esbuild... is that correct?  My builder is set as "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser" in angular.json.

Comment: far as I know it still uses esbuild for building your bundle (as it's literal orders of magnitude faster than any other builder) but maybe someone else with more knowledge can comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it manualy. Just ensure that all your dependencies already support Angular 16. If it is you can go to your `package.json` and set version for each dependency you want to update. Then run `npm install`. If all the dependencies correct you will have `package-lock.json` updated, if not you will see error and will know which dependencies must be updated too.

Comment: ok, I put typescript at "^4.9.3", zone at "^0.13.3", and all angular stuff to "^16.2.12".  When I run npm install, I keep getting a dependency error of : " Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.12" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.12  I'm a bit confused about that "^16.0.0" bit there...

Comment: if I add the --force flag, I end up with errors about not being able to remove directories, and some about "esbuild.exe"... so I think it's still trying to run it for some reason.

Comment: I'm guessing that the angular build component is trying to update @esbuild (even though I don't need it) in node_modules and my silly locked down environment is preventing it.

Comment: Yep. I clearly see at list one problem. https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/blob/main/package.json . It supports angular 16.1.* max. Also it is interesting that npm outdated doesnt show you next major version of angular in wanted column. I think some of your packages have no version for angular 16 yet.

Comment: not sure why ng-multiselect-dropdown is still in there... I think I tried it out, but ended up going a different route.

Comment: I managed to get things up to 15.2.10 by doing: npm install @angular/cli@15.2.10 -g  Then ng upgrade @angular/cli@15.2.10 and ng upgrade @angular/common. (though not sure doing it that way was actually necessary...)  But going to 16.x failed... I've got to call the IT guys to deal with it.  (it ends up with permissions issues when trying to remove directories (rmdir) and running esbuild.exe -v.  I also get a bunch of warnings about babel being deprecated.